# Would using feedback from an identical prior assignment to improve the new assignment be considered academic misconduct?

Tags: self-plagiarism

Several months prior, I submitted a very late assignment due to personal issues in my real life. My tutor was kind enough to mark it and give me full, proper feedback and even a score and under his recommendation and my own decision, I deferred the course until I'd gotten my life back in a more stable state.

I am now restarting the course and the assignment is the same. Would doing a new assignment using none of my original work since I got a rather poor grade using the feedback I got from the first one count as academic dishonesty?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "using".  Learning from it, fine.  Copying from it, not fine.  Anyway, for any question about "is X academic dishonesty", the best answer is "ask the instructor".  If everyone here thinks it's fine but your instructor has an obscure rule against it, you're going to get in trouble anyway - so only the instructor can give you the answer that will stick.

Answer (score 5):

No. You got that feedback and you can't be expected to "forget it" when writing the new assignment. Feedback is given in the hope that you learn from it; it would be bizarre to expect that you ignore it. If they want to avoid that students use information given out in connection with the earlier assignment, they have to set a different assignment.

Comment: This. It can actually be quite infuriating as an instructor when students adopt some bizarre honor code preventing them from doing the job. "I will spend a week cramming Bessel function tables for an open book exam because using the book is cheating and I must have it all in my head" - these tabular values are NOT what the course is about (and it is not even about Bessel functions!).

Comment: Actually, I'd make it stronger. It isn't that you can't be expected to forget it. It is really that you are expected to take advantage of it; to learn from it. But yes, definitely start over for the new version.